# How to create a library module to expand Dancer2 main script

Tags: perl, dancer

I would like to create a relatively complex web application. For that I find very convenient the [Dancer2](http://perldancer.org/) way of programming using the provided [DSL](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dancer2::Manual) (Domain-Specific Language). I also find the set of provided libraries excelent.

According to the documentation, if you wanted to split your main script in several libraries, you would use:

```
use Dancer2 appname => 'MyApp';
```

At the beginning of the *other* libraries. This is quite useful, but I would like to go a step further and define a library used by the main one to add more functionality in a modular way. I have tried:

```
package MyLibrary;
use Dancer2 appname => 'MyApp';
```

Then, in order to export variables and functions:

```
require Exporter;
our (@ISA, @EXPORT, @EXPORT_OK);
@ISA       = qw(Exporter);
@EXPORT    = qw( func1 func2 );
@EXPORT_OK = qw( func3 );
```

But I have found that these definitions are not exported. I can still access any function from the main script in the usual *long* way `MyLibrary::func1` but not with `func1`. This happens as soon as I add `use Dancer2 appname => 'MyApp';`. But if I don't do that, I cannot access any application specific data from inside the library. Say I want to check a configuration option like `config->{myoption}`.

So, am I trying to do something that should be done in a different way? Is there a way around this? I am using Dancer2 version 0.205002.